# Dynamic PDF generation from PDF template in Java without formatting issue

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a sample PDF which is having some placeholders, from which I need to generate PDF with Dynamic values in place of 'placeholders'. I need to do this in Java technologies. What should be the approach?

(Note: sample PDF having placeholders, Table structures, paragraphs, Stylesheets).

Comment: If those place holders are Acrofields you can use iText to read in the pdf, grab the fields, stamp the fields and save down your final product.

Comment: You mention a *sample PDF*? Can you share it?

Comment: @scrappedcola :I have read some blogs that ,I loose the formatting if I replace the string for pdf template with AcroFields but first requirement it self is I should not looseformatting.Is that true?

Comment: I have a project where we fill in pdf's using acrofields without issue. Format of the pdf stays, even when reordering and such. The only thing to watch out for is to ensure the acrofield is large enough to contain the data you are entering.

Answer (score -5):

We, as iText team, has been receiving this exact question more and more everyday since many people/organisations want to generate custom filled PDF files with data they have. Many of them design forms in PDF and then they fill in the form programmatically. However there are problems with this solution: 1. You need license for a product where you will design the form 2. You need license (if applicable) for the PDF library to fill in the form 3. You (with your team) need to spend time to write the code where you fill in the form 4. You need to repeat all those each time you want to update your form etc. 5. Your form is most likely a static form, meaning that, for example, in case of an invoice you need to foresee how many rows you need to put in your form when designing it. What happens if users have more items than you foresee? You can use XFA forms but you probably know the cost of the designer and all other problems that come along with this deprecated technology.

We, as iText, bring a solution to all those problem just like we did in other tools we have. The solution is called iText DITO in which you design your PDF template in a WYSIWYG browser based editor. No coding is needed. If you want extra styling in your PDF, you can add CSS at any time. You can specify data-binding to elements in your design. Once you are done with your design, your project is basically ready to be deployed. If you need to generate tons of high-quality PDF files based on your template, you will use iText DITO back-end SDK to push your custom data (linking to data binding you have in your template) and your PDF files are created instantly.